# Flutter: App not authorised to use firebase + safety_net_token issues despite correct SHA-1/SHA-256 key

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, firebase-app-check

I am running a **RELEASE** build on my Android phone. The debug version works fine. I am using AppCheck as well.

I get the following error when authenticating the phone number:
[image]

I have followed the AppCheck tutorial [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/usage/#activating-the-debug-provider-android). I have not done any steps for the DEBUG part.

I have rechecked the SHA-256, SHA 1 and package name codes with Firebase console and they all are fine. What could I be doing wrong here?